# Array within an array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is this array with in array declaration correct? and if it is correct how can I output or atleast alert all the contents in the chkArray?

```
var chkArray = { tv_type[],screen_size[],connectivity[],features[]};
var tv_type = [];
var screen_size = [];
var connectivity = [];
var features = [];
```

Comment: you can use the `$.each()` function to iterate through your arrays. Documentation [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: I think you will get an error since you are trying to use your arrays before they are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define array according variable scope

```
var tv_type = [];
var screen_size = [];
var connectivity = [];
var features = [];

//incorrect syntax
/*var chkArray = { tv_type[],screen_size[],connectivity[],features[]};*/

//change to 
var chkArray = [tv_type,screen_size,connectivity,features];
```

For debug Try this

```
alert(JSON.stringify(chkArray))
```

OR

```
console.log(chkArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an object with arrays in it even though you are asking for arrays in array. It's more meaningful for your usecase. A bit like this

```
var chkArray = {
    tv_type: [],
    screen_size: [],
    connectivity: [],
    features: []
}
```

To access them you can say:

```
chkArray.tv_type[index]
```

And push items:

```
chkArray.tv_type.push("LCD");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare a multidimensional array like this

Possible solution will be

```
var arrayA = [];
var arrayB = [];
var arrayC = []; 
var arrayTotal = [arrayA,arrayB,arrayC];
```

and you can use

```
console.log(arrayTotal)
```

to print the array in console